# How can I set numerous onClick() by loop?

Tags: android, button

Recently, I have been making a simple board game android app. This game takes place on 7x7 grid, and I have made buttons for all of the squares.

This is not my first time doing this, and not only making the layout but also writing `onClick()` for each of those buttons were hard work. Thanks to the matrix array(`int state[7][7]` and `Button board[][]=new Button[7][7]`), I can shove all 49 codes into one function, but writing like

```
board[0][0]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.board00);
board[0][1]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.board01);
int i;
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
  board[0][i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
      my_function(0,i);
  }
}
```

(I had to write somewhat full code because the last time I omitted a part of the code, everyone was talking that I missed that part.)

will make all the buttons focus on the resulting `i` rather than the number it is originally meant for. (I know that part, don't just end up telling me "That won't work because~".)

So, my question is this: is there any way to make the `[i][j]` button to call `my_function(i,j)` for *each* of the `i` and `j`, rather than typing one by one or generating the code?

P.S. I didn't do much activities here, and I don't know how to look for my type of questions effectively, or verify if any question actually has my answer. If you find any question with the same answer, please tell me. I did search for this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the anonymous class then this should work

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
  final int ii = i;
  final int jj = j;
  board[j][i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
      my_function(ii, jj);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an anonymous class.  Make a full class.  Then it can have a constructor you can call and pass in parameters.  For example

```
private static class MyButtonListener implements OnClickListener {
    int i;
    int j;
    public MyButtonListener(int i, int j) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }
    public void onClick(View v){
      my_function(i, j);
    }
}
```

Then in your loops, create a `new MyButtonListener(i,j)` instead of an anonymous class.

Comment: I don't think I did much understanding. Can you write a short code about creating a `new MyButtonListener(i,j)`?